# vuejs semantic ui - drop down not displaying on arrow click

Tags: vuejs2, semantic-ui

I'm faced with an issue where my semantic drop down in my vue project won't activate when clicking on the arrow icon but works when I click on the rest of the element. The drop down also works when I set the dropdown to activate on hover, but just not on click. Solutions I've tried:

- tested if the dynamic id are at fault
- tested if the back ticks are confusing things
- placed the values directly into the semantic drop down

Aside from the dropdown not activating, the code below works as intended and brings back the selected value to the parent component and can be displayed.

**Dropdown.vue:**

```
<template>
    <div class="ui selection dropdown" :id="`drop_${dropDownId}`">

        <input type="hidden" name="gender" v-model="selected">
        <i class="dropdown icon"></i>
        <div class="default text">Gender</div>
        <div class="menu">
            <div class="item" v-for="option in options" v-bind:data-value="option.value">
                {{ option.text }}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    data: function () {
      return {
        selected: {}
      }
    },
    watch: {
        selected: function (){
          this.$emit("dropDownChanged", this.selected)
        }
    },
    props: {
      options: Array, //[{text, value}]
      dropDownId: String
    },
    mounted () {
      let vm = this;
      $(`#drop_${vm.dropDownId}`).dropdown({
            onChange: function (value, text, $selectedItem) {
              vm.selected = value;
            },
        forceSelection: false,
        selectOnKeydown: false,
        showOnFocus: false,
        on: "click"
          });
    }
  }
</script>
```

**The component usage:**

```
<vue-drop-down :options="dropDownOptions" dropDownId="drop1" @dropDownChanged="dropDownSelectedValue = $event"></vue-drop-down>
```

**The data in the parent:**

```
dropDownOptions: [
          { text: 'One', value: 'A' },
          { text: 'Two', value: 'B' },
          { text: 'Three', value: 'C' }
        ],
        dropDownSelectedValue: ""
```

Here is a fiddle of the above but simplified to use a flatter project. However the problem doesn't reproduce :(

https://jsfiddle.net/eywraw8t/210520/

Comment: I have a feeling that there's an overlapping element on the arrow but I'm not sure how to look for it, what is causing it or how to fix it

Comment: scratch that, it's just that the icon doesn't stretch to the very last pixel on the element on the right hand side. So i'm still stumped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what is causing your issue (as the examples on the Semantic Ui website look similar), but there is a workaround. For you arrow icon:

```
<i @click="toggleDropDownVisibility" class="dropdown icon"></i>
```

And then in the methods section of your Vue component:

```
methods: {
  toggleDropDownVisibility () {
    $(`#drop_${this.dropDownId}`)
    .dropdown('toggle');
  }
},
```